# Duda sobre sscanf

Tags: c

El programa me pide que con las fechas que he leido anteriormente con fscanf , sepa cuantos años tiene la persona , he supuesto que tengo que usar el sscanf (si no es asi me gustaria que me dijesen y ayudasen pls) dejo el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char linea1[100],linea2[100],tab[100],tab1[100],prueba[100];
int ano,mes,dia;
FILE *f1;
f1=fopen("h.txt","r");
fgets(linea1,100,f1);
fgets(linea2,100,f1);
int i=0;
while(!feof(f1)){
    fscanf(f1,"%[^\t] %[^\t] %s  ",tab,tab1,prueba);
     printf("%s//",prueba);
     sscanf(prueba,"%d/%d/%d",&ano,&mes,&dia);
     printf("%d \n",&ano);
}

}
```

Aqui les dejo el txt por si lo necesitan:

```
Fecha Examen: 2018/08/09
Numero de pruebas: 6
23321223D Markel Zubieta    4.47 3.06 5.09 5.11 8.18 7.95 6.44 3.79 8.12 5.33   2000/2/3
13080976G Antonio Gonzalez Perez    3.51 2.08 3.01 4.71 1943/12/21
34235676F Jose Luis Martinez Garcia 2.26 1.85 9.05 9.80 4.39    1986/2/29
X345432Y Victor Mayo    2.58 4.09 5.9 2.6 6.3 7.1 4.24 5.08 2000/11/12
20205632S Silva Martinez Fernandez  0.86 2.62 8.01 0.9 9.2 7 4.89 5.79 2.37 7   1970/04/10
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de `fscanf` te presento `strtok`, una función útil para dividir string en partes.

```
char *strtok(char *s1, const char *s2);
```

> Rompe la cadena s1 en segmentos o tókens. Esta ruptura destruye s1, en
> el proceso. La forma de romper la cadena depende de la secuencia de
> caracteres de la cadena s2. La cadena se rompe reemplazando el delimitador encontrado con '\0'. Estos caracteres se denominan [caracteres]
> delimitadores. La función recorrerá la cadena en busca de alguno de
> los delimitadores de la cadena s2. Cuando lo encuentre, el proceso se
> detiene, ya que tiene un token. Posteriores llamadas a strtok romperán
> la cadena s1 en otros tókens. Estas llamadas pueden tener otra
> secuencia de delimitadores.

*Valor de retorno:*

> La primera llamada a strtok determina la cadena a romper, retornando
> el puntero al comienzo del primer token. Si se recorrió la cadena s1
> sin haber encontrado un delimitador, y aún no se ha obtenido el primer
> token, entonces la función retornará un puntero nulo.
>
> Posteriores llamadas retornarán más tokens. Si ya no encuentra más
> delimitadores, entonces retornará todos los caracteres desde el último
> delimitador para ser el último token. Si ya se retornó el último
> token, entonces retornará un puntero nulo con demás llamadas a la
> función.

Ejemplo:

La linea

```
char* linea = "23321223D Markel Zubieta 4.47 3.06 5.09 5.11 8.18 7.95 6.44 3.79 8.12 5.33 2000/2/3"
```

pasada por `strtok` retorna punteros a los siguientes substrings:

```
-> 23321223D
-> Markel
-> Zubieta
-> 4.47
-> 3.06
-> 5.09
-> 5.11
-> 8.18
-> 7.95
-> 6.44
-> 3.79
-> 8.12
-> 5.33
-> 2000/2/3
-> (null)
```

**Código**

La idea es leer una línea completa y dividirla usando espacio como delimitador. Luego recorremos los tokens encontrados, clasificandolos según su posición y/o caracter inicial.

Nota: No hay manejo de errores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char linea[100]
    FILE *f1;
    
    f1 = fopen("h.txt", "r");
    fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), f1);
    fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), f1);
    
    while (fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), f1)) {
        
        char* dni = strtok(linea, " ");
        // Leer las partes del nombres y armar un nombre completo.
        char* nombre = strtok(0, " ");
        char* palabra = strtok(0, " ");
        while (palabra && isalpha(*palabra)) {
            // Reemplazar el '\0' anterior por un ' ', para concatenar
            // este nombre al anterior.
            *(palabra - 1) = ' ';
            palabra = strtok(0, " ");
            }
        
        //  Leer todos el resto como nota.
        char* notas[12];
        int n_notas = 0;
        for (n_notas = 0; n_notas < 12 && palabra; n_notas++) {
            notas[n_notas] = palabra;
            palabra = strtok(0, " ");
            }
        //  La ultima no era una nota, sino una fecha,
        //  sacarla de la lista de notas.
        n_notas--;
        char* fecha = notas[n_notas];
        n_notas--;
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombre);
        printf("Notas: ");
        for (int i=0; i < n_notas; i++) {
            printf("%s ", notas[i]);
            }
        printf("\nFecha: %s", fecha);
        printf("---------------------\n");
        }         
}
```

Produce:

```
Nombre: Markel Zubieta
Notas: 4.47 3.06 5.09 5.11 8.18 7.95 6.44 3.79 8.12 
Fecha: 2000/2/3
---------------------
Nombre: Antonio Gonzalez Perez
Notas: 3.51 2.08 3.01 
Fecha: 1943/12/21
---------------------
Nombre: Jose Luis Martinez Garcia
Notas: 2.26 1.85 9.05 9.80 
Fecha: 1986/2/29
---------------------
Nombre: Victor Mayo
Notas: 2.58 4.09 5.9 2.6 6.3 7.1 4.24 
Fecha: 2000/11/12
---------------------
Nombre: Silva Martinez Fernandez
Notas: 0.86 2.62 8.01 0.9 9.2 7 4.89 5.79 2.37 
Fecha: 1970/04/10
---------------------
```